# Comparing a dictionary with list as values and a dictionary to generate values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Please, I need help to compare the two dictionaries below, with a generator.

```
r = {1:['1', '2', '3'], 2:['1', '2', '3'], 3:['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']}

d = {2: 2, 1: 4, 3: 1}

for k,v in d.items():
    if k == 2 and v == 1:
        print(r[2][1])
    if k == 2 and v == 2:
        print(r[2][2])
    if k == 2 and v == 3:
        print(r[2][3])
```

What I want to do is to print from r, the value that is equal to the key and value in d. the code worked as I have tried it as in the above. but I cannot keep doing if-if things please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can index directly, handling exceptions as appropriate:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    try:
        print(r[k][v])
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        pass

# 3
# 2
```

`KeyError` may be raised if the first indexer `k` is not a dictionary key. `IndexError` may be raised if the second indexer `v` is too large given a dictionary list value. You should define carefully which errors to capture and how to manage them.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the lengths of the values in each key and the dictionary itself to achieve the desired result using the following:

```
r = {1:['1', '2', '3'], 2:['1', '2', '3'], 3:['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']}
d = {2: 2, 1: 4, 3: 1}

for k,v in d.items():
    if k < len(r) and v < len(r[k]):
        print(r[k][v])
```